# Converting deprecated dynamic_rnn to TensorFlow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I was recently reworking on an older application using `tf.compat.v1.nn.dynamic_rnn` as one of the methods. The code block as a whole is:

```
all_lstm_outputs, self.state = tf.compat.v1.nn.dynamic_rnn(
        drop_multi_cell, all_inputs, initial_state=tuple(initial_state),
        time_major = True, dtype=tf.float32)
```

However, the version is no longer working on 2.0, and I'm looking to convert the code into `tf.keras.layers.RNN`.

For other context, `drop_multi_cell = tf.keras.layers.StackedRNNCells(drop_lstm_cells)`, but I have difficulty seeing how the code fits into the latest module.

I'm testing with:

```
rnn_layer = tf.keras.layers.RNN([drop_multi_cell],
                                time_major=True)
        all_lstm_outputs, self.state = rnn_layer(all_inputs, initial_state=tuple(initial_state))
```

but it doesn't seen right.

For other contexts,

[https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/nn/dynamic_rnn](https://stackoverflow.com)
[https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/RNN](https://stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

In TensorFlow 2.x, the tf.keras.layers.RNN is used to create a recurrent layer for your model. You are on the right track, but there are a few adjustments to make in order to properly use tf.keras.layers.RNN with your drop_multi_cell.

Kindly follow this steps to resolve the issue:

> Firstly need to import Tensorflow.

> Define the drop_lstm_cells and Create drop_multi_cell using tf.keras.layers.StackedRNNCells.

> Create the rnn_layer using tf.keras.layers.RNN, passing drop_multi_cell directly.

> And Use the rnn_layer with inputs all_inputs and initial state initial_state.

Now, this should correctly convert your code to use tf.keras.layers.RNN in TensorFlow 2.x.
The rnn_layer will have return_sequences=True and return_state=True to ensure you get both the outputs and the final state.

The time_major=True argument keeps the input and output tensors in time-major format, which seems to be what you had in the original tf.compat.v1.nn.dynamic_rnn call.